# Computer wakes and sleeps every ten minutes

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep

I have a Windows 10 laptop and I've noticed, although I'm not sure how long it's been occurring, that after closing the laptop and it enters sleep mode, it will wake up every so often then go immediately back to sleep throughout the night. But this does not happen every night. There are no scheduled tasks and no wake timers set. I did notice that after nights when it does occur, I'll check the Windows logs and find that it would consistently wake up every ten minutes throughout the night.

When I first close the lid I get the following suspicious log information.

> Process C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\a4\AdaptiveSleepService.exe (process ID:7352) reset policy scheme from {8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c} to {8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c}

Followed two seconds later by the Kernel-Power message

> The system is entering sleep.
> Sleep Reason: Button or Lid

Then followed one second later by the Kernel-Power message

> The system has resumed from sleep.

The computer remains asleep (even though the last message said it resumed from sleep) for ten minutes before waking up, kicking on the fans for a few seconds, logging several other messages, and finishing by logging those last two messages again and going to sleep for ten more minutes. Some of the additional messages before the final two "entering/resumed" messages are logged after each subsequent waking include, from Kernel-Power

> Firmware S3 times. ResumeCount: 136, FullResume: 755, AverageResume: 758

where the ResumeCount increments by one every ten minutes when it wakes, and this message from Power-Troubleshooter

> The system has returned from a low power state.
>
> Sleep Time: ‎2020‎-‎09‎-‎12T16:16:38.977842700Z Wake Time:
> ‎2020‎-‎09‎-‎12T16:16:38.977842700Z
>
> Wake Source: S4 Doze to Hibernate

This repeats all night and I can't figure out why or how to make it stop. Any advice?

Comment: Run the computer manufacturer's Driver Update App, update all drivers especially including BIOS and Power Driver.  Restart after all this, and test again.

Comment: Also, after the above, turn Hibernation OFF until things are sorted out, then make sure suspend timings are not too short (i.e., suspend not less than 15 or 30 minutes of inactivitly).

Comment: I would counsel some deep antivirus scans.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I just installed BIOS driver/firmware updates, and hibernation has already been turned off. I doubt it's a virus as I'm overly cautious and knowledgeable on that front. I'll see if that fixes things over the next few times I close the laptop and see what happens.

Comment: I had the same once, although for me getting the status of last wake gave me the cause: VirtualBox. If I had that open, it would just resume 10 minutes later.

Comment: You may want to keep the lid open, put the pc to standby, get it to wake up by itself, then get a powercfg -lastwake. I think because you opening the lid means the last wake was happening by you

Comment: It seems that updating the drivers didn't fix it. Sometimes after closing the lid the computer will wake and go back to sleep every two minutes all night, which is even worse. Sometimes it doesn't and stays asleep just fine. I have no clue what could be the problem.

Comment: I think it's easier at this point to find sources of the problem by systematically excluding problem areas. I would suggest do check the HW layer first, by installing a "fresh" minimal system on a external drive. Linux if you have enough know how. See if sleep works there.